# How can I replace HTML with JQuery when Radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the HTML and replace the DIV (not show and hide them). Someone told me that replacing HTML in jQuery is not a good idea. Can someone help me with the best way to change or replace the HTML in this code to show new buttons (not hide and show). Thank you for your feedback. I'm learning everyday thanks you!

```js
 function change_button(){   
    //join pro buttons
     $("input[name=members-buttons]").on( "change", function() {
       var enabled = $(this).val();
      
       $(".none").hide();
       $("#"+enabled).show();
     });   
        
   }
      
    change_button();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="members-buttons" value="buyers-button">
  Buyers / Tenant <br>
  <input type="radio" name="members-buttons" value="agent-button">
  Agent / Landlord <br>
  <div id="button-container">
<div class="none join-now-btn-container" id="members-disabled-btn"> <a href="/register" class="btn logo-color-btn">Join Now Disabled</a> </div>
<br>
    <div class="none join-now-btn-container" id="buyers-button"> <a href="/register" class="btn logo-color-btn">Join Now</a> </div>
    <br>
    <div class="none join-now-btn-container" id="agent-button"> <a href="/pro-membership-packages" class="btn logo-color-btn">Join Now</a> </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: "Someone told me that replacing HTML in jQuery is not a good idea." Why is that? And why what is wrong using hide/show?

Comment: I forgot to add a disabled button DIV in the code. But I would like to show a disabled button, and have that DIV replaced whenever a user clicks on the radio item.

Comment: update your question with that too @JamesStar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing a lot of changes of the html with jQuery in a lot of web applications without any problem, so I don't know why they told you that.

Check this example. I placed the url in the option value which will be used in the link when selected. I don't know if you are really sending that form or it's only a way to custom the Join link.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name=members-buttons]").on("change", function() {
    var sel = $(this).val();

    $('#button-container').empty();

    jQuery('<a/>', {
      href: sel,
      class: 'btn logo-color-btn',
      html: 'Join Now'
    }).appendTo('#button-container');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="members-buttons" value="/register" /> Buyers / Tenant <br>
  <input type="radio" name="members-buttons" value="/pro-membership-packages" /> Agent / Landlord <br>
</form>
<div id="button-container"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution to a simple question. Thank you.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Business Catalyst to build a website and the suggestion was to use Liquid Mark-up instead of .html(). But the simple jQuery approach works best.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change_button() {
  //join pro buttons
  $('.none').hide();
  $("input[name=members-buttons]").on("change", function() {
    $('.none').show();
    var enabled = $(this).val();
    if(enabled == 'buyers-button'){ 
      $('.logo-color-btn').attr('href','/register');
      $('.logo-color-btn').html('Join Now As Agent');
    }
    else{
      $('.logo-color-btn').attr('href','/pro-membership-packages');
       $('.logo-color-btn').html('Join Now As Pro Member');
    }
  });

}

change_button();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="members-buttons" value="buyers-button"> Buyers / Tenant <br>
  <input type="radio" name="members-buttons" value="agent-button"> Agent / Landlord <br>
  <div id="button-container">
    <div class="none join-now-btn-container" id="buyers-button"> <a href="/register" class="btn logo-color-btn">Join Now</a> </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Please check the code might help you in solving your issue

Thanks